# Check if value > 0

Tags: javascript

Are the following expressions equal in all cases?

```
if(obj.val && obj.val > 0){...}
```

and

```
if(obj.val){...}
```

Can I use the simpler latter expression?

**Update:**

Can I use just `obj.val > 0` instead?

Comment: If `obj.val` is negative, the first condition will be false, but the second will be true.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Is it? Have you tried?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi or if `obj.val` isn't a number at all

Comment: Well it depends. If you know that `val` is a property of `obj` and contains a number then you can just use `obj.val > 0`.

Comment: If you don't know anything then you may overkill: `typeof(obj) === 'object' && 'val' in obj && typeof(obj.val) === 'number' && obj.val > 0`

Answer (score 2):

No. If `obj.val === -1` (Or any negative number for that matter), the first expression is `false` and the second is `true`.

```
> Boolean(-1 && -1 > 0)
false
> Boolean(-1)
true
```

#### Update

If you're absolutely sure that `obj` is a defined object, you may use just `obj.val > 0`, yes. Beware of funky behavior with type convertion in case `obj.val` is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. Consider

```
obj = { val: -1 };
```

Then your first expression will be falsy and the second will be truthy.

Comment: @Royi They aren't ... Negative numbers are truthy.

Comment: Miss read the question. I thought Fredric refer in "first condition" to `obj.val` as a first part in `obj.val && obj.val > 0` But  he referred  to first expression as the whole `obj.val && obj.val > 0`.